# Yum finds package in search but can't find it to install

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I got this issue on an FC8 server where if I search for something in yum, it finds the packages I am searching for but then when I go to install the package it says its not there...?

```
[hamstar@tankian ~]$ yum search pecl
php-pecl-apc.i386 : APC caches and optimizes PHP intermediate code

[hamstar@tankian ~]$ sudo yum install php-pecl-apc.i386
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package php-pecl-apc.i386 available.
Nothing to do

[hamstar@tankian ~]$ sudo yum install php-pecl-apc
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package php-pecl-apc available.
Nothing to do
```

wtf?

EDIT: Yum update shows this:

```
[hamstar@tankian ~]$ sudo yum update
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

EDIT: I also tried this and tried it all again with no luck:

```
[hamstar@tankian ~]$ sudo yum clean all
Cleaning up Everything
```

EDIT: So i just realized this package is installed, but replacing the package name for pyqt (and variations of) which is not installed gives the same results.  Here is the output for a package that is already installed on my other FC8 server.

```
[root@dolmayan ~]# yum install php
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Package php - 5.2.4-3.i386 is already installed.
Nothing to do
```

**RESOLUTION**
In Alex's comment down there he said go to [this fedora wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Enabling_new_signing_key#What_do_I_have_to_do.3F) so I did and followed the commands:

```
wget http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/fedora-release/8/6.transition/data/signed/4f2a6fd2/noarch/fedora-release-8-6.transition.noarch.rpm
su -c 'rpm -Uvh fedora-release-8-6.transition.noarch.rpm'
```

Got the key from [here](http://keys.gnupg.net:11371/pks/lookup?search=0x6DF2196F&op=get) emptied the old gpg key and pasted the new one into it.

```
su -c 'echo > /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-8-and-9
sudo vi /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-8-and-9
```

Then I ran:

```
su -c 'rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-8-and-9'
```

Done!

Comment: The actual problem isn't search vs. install, but "running as user" vs. "running as root". As they can have different caches. You can also run with "yum search -v blah" to get a lot more info. (like the repository the package is in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

and then try

```
sudo yum -y install php-pecl-apc
```

Comment: No luck with this either :(

Comment: I am recalling that F8 was affected by the signing key compromise a while ago, and you needed to update the keys.  If it has been a while since you have attempted any updates on the box, I would make sure that you have the "fedora-release-8-6.transition" package installed (rpm -qa|grep release)

And if not, check out https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Enabling_new_signing_key#What_do_I_have_to_do.3F

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the arch from the package spec:

```
[hamstar@tankian ~]$ sudo yum install php-pecl-apc
```

Comment: Yea I tried this too sorry, also didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Do a yum update and try again. This happens when your local package index is getting old and new versions of packages are beeing released.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but no cigar :(

Answer (score 0):

The package isn't already installed, is it?

```
yum list installed | grep pecl
```

Comment: Oh it is installed, I was just using it as an example tho... replace php-pecl-apc with pyqt which is not installed and it does exactly the same, I've tried pyQt, pyqt, pyqt.i386 and pyQt.i386.

Comment: Updated question with output from a working yum install for a package that is already installed on my other FC8 box.

Comment: Running "yum list installed '*pecl*'" is much better than using grep.